# How to change the title font size in this jekyll theme?

Tags: github, jekyll

I tried to find the "title" section so that i could change the font size. 
I want to decrease it a little but i have not been able to find it in the main.css file. Maybe i'm not looking in the right file or for the right part to change? 
Any help would be appreciated.

This is the theme: https://github.com/daattali/beautiful-jekyll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title itself is in the  element.

Its size is in:

- [`main.css#intro-header .page-heading h1`](https://github.com/daattali/beautiful-jekyll/blob/7b43e4061dd795cb3be91b47f828ea6d72cd7dcf/css/main.css#L471-L478)
- [`main.css#intro-header .page-heading h1`](https://github.com/daattali/beautiful-jekyll/blob/7b43e4061dd795cb3be91b47f828ea6d72cd7dcf/css/main.css#L514-L535) (when `min-width: 768px`)

To quickly see that, type <kbd>F12</kbd> in our Chrome/Firefox browser, and select what you want to see, using the [demo website for that template](https://deanattali.com/beautiful-jekyll/):

[image: Page CSS inspection]

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I spent quite some time scrolling through the css files but i didn't know what to look for.

Comment: @WiredMaker No problem. I have edited the answer to show you exactly how I pinpointed the right CSS file/line.

Comment: Do you know how to change the header color in the same css file? I cannot seem to find where to change it. - Also the subtitle.